# JavaScript html scroll like in iOS

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, touchscreen, stagewebviewbridge

I'm creating a Flash Air application for desktop. The goal is to create an app that opens up a webpage, shows virtual keyboard and duplicates the behaviour of scrolling like in iOS browser : you scroll with your finger - not with the scrollbar.

As I'm creating it on desktop, I need to scroll it with the mouse.The application is nearly complete. I'm connecting webpage with Air application using StageWebViewBridge. Now I need to create touch screen effect for scroll.

To do that - I need JavaScript. Can anyoone suggest something ?

Here's the reference : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/list
PS : This is Sencha framework - suited for mobile devices. I need that kind of dragging scroll on my desctop device!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the same kind of scrolling like in iOS you should search for **momentum scrolling**. You'll find, for example, those JavaScript libraries "iScroll" and "Scrollability". Take a look, how they manage the scrolling.

Also interesting is this article on how scrolling on iOS works:

http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/10/flick-list-with-its-momentum-scrolling-and-deceleration.html

Hope this helps, and happy refactoring. ;)